# Solr Query on Unique Integer Field

Tags: full-text-search, solr

I have a field defined in schema.xml as:

```
<field name="id" type="integer" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
```

It is also the `uniqueKey` for the schema.

I cannot perform a query on this field with the query url:

```
/select?q=4525&qf=id&fl=id,name%2Cscore
```

This returns no results, however, if I search on a different field(such as a text field), with a different query, I get many results, which include the stored id.  Solr is working great for text fields, but I cannot query for items based on the unique id.

What am I missing?  Are there other steps that need to be performed for indexing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like you're using the [qf parameter](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMaxRequestHandler#head-af452050ee272a1c88e2ff89dc0012049e69e180) the wrong way... it's only meant to be used to boost fields in dismax queries. 
Use `id:4525` instead, as in:

```
/select?q=id:4525&fl=id,name,score
```