# Solr/ElasticSearch - Document lookup by ID -> query or filterQuery?

Tags: solr, elasticsearch

I just wonder what I am supposed to use for a lookup by ID.

This thread [Solr Query on Unique Integer Field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075761/solr-query-on-unique-integer-field) seems to use a query.

But it is not what is said here: [Search document by id very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8472948/search-document-by-id-very-slow)

And here: http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Solr-Unique-Key-Field-Should-Apply-on-q-search-or-fq-search-td4003066.html
But I'm not reusing the same query because the lookups can be on any ID

---

ElasticSearch provides natively a lookup by id, someone knows what is happening under the hood of ElasticSearch lookup so that I can eventually use the same strategy with Solr?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should still use Filter Query cause you may search the same id some time later which would be much faster in performance in comparison to the `q` query

`fq` - Provide an optional filtering query.
Results of the query are restricted to searching only those results returned by the filter query. [Filtered queries are cached by Solr](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrCaching#filterCache). 
They are very useful for improving the speed of complex queries.